# Breakdown of the median

Tags: median, estimators, robust

I am looking for an accessible review of the breakdown properties of the median (estimator of location) and possible practical solutions for dealing with it.

(By *accessible* I mean short and readable by a non-statistician, although at ease with math. If you can review the main points in the answer's section, it could be sufficient.)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "dealing with it"?

Comment: Robust estimation of a sample mean is a part of a bigger algorithm that I am working on. I have identified some obvious cases where it breaks down - e.g., when I have only one good data point and one outlier (whereas everything else is missing data). I however would like to have a more general solution for less obvious cases.

Comment: Are you asking about the *mean* or the *median*?  They are different properties and, unless you make special assumptions, usually have different estimators.

Comment: There are actually two estimators there: one is simple median, the other is using Huber weight.

Comment: The nature of your question is still unclear: now you have mentioned *three* estimators of *at least two different quantities* but you still haven't explained what problem "dealing with it" is supposed to address!

Comment: Have you previously worked on applied problems involving robust estimation?

Comment: Yes, for over 30 years in hundreds of cases--but why does it matter?

Comment: I am looking for a piece of advice - it would be very kind of you, if you help. Part of the problem is rather generic: the robust estimation works in 99.99% of the time, but sometimes it does break (as known by comparison with another method and related data samples). What is the way of handling such situations? I suppose, at the minimum, I have to be able to detect the breakdown. Then I would also want to have the number, rather than discard the data altogether.

Comment: It's very hard to give advice without knowing the problem!